# Simple steganography with python 3 / PIL

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, steganography

I have a problem with a basic steganography script in Python, using PIL.

Here is my goal: I want to store four MSB of the pixel values of every bands of an image I want to hide. Then store them in the four LSB of another image. In order to reveal the hidden image, I just want to extract the four LSB and add '0000'.

I know this is very destructive. But the image that hides should at least disapear. Actually it doesn't. I don't know what is wrong with my code. Could you help me please ?

```
from PIL import Image

global image, pixels, s_image, s_pixels

def hide_stegano():

    def new_pixel(pix, s_pix):
        return (pix & 240) | ((s_pix & 240) >> 4)

    l, h = image.size
    temp = Image.new('RGB', (l, h))
    temp_pix = temp.load()

    for i in range(l):
        for j in range(h):
            rgb = list(pixels[i, j])
            s_rgb = list(s_pixels[i, j])
            for band, (value, s_value) in enumerate(zip(rgb, s_rgb)):
                rgb[band] = new_pixel(value, s_value)

            temp_pix[i, j] = tuple(rgb)

    temp.save("temp.jpg")
    temp.show()


def reveal_stegano():

    def new_pixel(pix):
        return (pix & 15) << 4

    l, h = image.size
    temp = Image.new('RGB', (l, h))
    temp_pix = temp.load()

    for i in range(l):
        for j in range(h):
            rgb = list(pixels[i, j])
            for band, value in enumerate(rgb):
                rgb[band] = new_pixel(value)
            temp_pix[i, j] = tuple(rgb)

    temp.save("temp.jpg")
    temp.show()

image = Image.open("image1.jpg").convert('RGB')
pixels = image.load()
image.show()

# Hidden image
s_image = Image.open("image2.jpg").convert('RGB')
s_image = s_image.resize(image.size)
s_pixels = image.load()
s_image.show()


hide_stegano()


reveal_stegano()
```

Do you see something wrong ?

Best regards

Comment: Using `bin` and `int` to do bit manipulation is doing things the hard/slow way. Use bit manipulation operations instead.

Comment: bin_pix = str(bin(pix))[2:].zfill(8)
new_pix = bin_pix[4:] + '0000'

is actually << 4 ? Am I correct ?

Comment: You save the image to jpeg, which uses lossy compression and alters your pixel values. You can't use jpeg when you do direct pixel lsb modification/embedding steganography. There are myriads of questions on this site with this exact mistake.

Comment: thank you. Everything solved :) I swear I did search and I didn't see questions about jpeg.

Comment: I'm not accusing you of anything. If anything, most questions of this problem are worded in a way such that the error isn't apparent, because if you know what it causes it, the fix is trivial. I was just pointing out it's a fairly frequent mistake, one I also made the first time.